# UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY when installing private bower package from TFS

Tags: git, ssl, tfs, proxy, bower

My ultimate goal is to share packages of front-end code across applications developed within the same organisation. My strategy is to create Bower packages stored in GIT repos on TFS.

I've got a GIT repo set up correctly with the bower.json file in the root, and in the second project's folder I'm running:

bower install "https://tfs.hca.local/Shared/UserInterface/_git/Hca.Shared.Styles"

It returns the error UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

The TFS server and my machine are on the same LAN, but I need to also reach public bower packages on github through the corporate proxy. My .bowerrc file contains:

```
{
"proxy": "http://proxy.hca.local:8080",
"https-proxy": "http://proxy.hca.local:8080",
"ca": "C:/Users/William Warby/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
}
```

curl-ca-bundle.crt was copied from C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt, and I have added into it the root certificate for my TFS server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe add a `"no_proxy": ".hsc.local"` to avoid using the proxy for tfs urls.

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid that didn't help. I did found that by doubling the forward slashes in the ca property ("ca": "c://Users//William Warby//curl-ca-bundle.crt") I got past the problem with the SSL cert that I reported in this question, only to find a new problem - now it's giving me a 401 response because I'm not authenticating to the TFS server.